# Web UI for Delphi desktop app

Tags: ajax, delphi, user-interface, web

I want to develop Web UI for my desktop application to allow users do some tasks remotely. The Web UI server and desktop app will run on the same computer.

Question is: what is the best way to implement it?

I found several possible solutions:

1. The Delphi (I use 2010) has IntraWeb components, which should help to build the UI. Also, coding will be in Delphi IDE.
2. I also found Morfik - looks solid, but it will require some learning from my side.

Please push me to the right direction :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Web Application Framework for Delphi is recommended?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793112/what-web-application-framework-for-delphi-is-recommended)

Comment: It'a about developing web apps from scratch, but I need to create a web front-end for existing app. Also strange that no one mentioned IntraWeb there.

Answer (score 7):

I have tried UniGui and it's a really good choice. Have a look at their site ([www.unigui.com](http://www.unigui.com)) and see for yourself.

Basically, you create a new UniGUI app and use dedicated components from the palette. You can use the same application for both desktop and web purposes. Plus, it can be compiled as an ISAPI module with ease. :)

Comment: Looks interesting but I could not find any licensing information on that page. Does anybody know?

Comment: It's based on ExtJS, so despite the fact that UniGUI is free, you need to buy the ExtJS license.

Comment: It's also possible that uniGUI will become non-free after beta testing is over.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to make more complex webapps in Delphi (isapi, intraweb etc..) all is so heavy and difficult !

Just put a tcp server on your application and make the website with Php very easily just send your commands to app using with fsocket functions library

I think that is most easy and best way other way I don't trust to any httpserver applications if it's not apache:)